# What is SELECT for SUM, GROUPed and DISTINCTed by another columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, distinct

**This is content of my table:**

```
date cat.  price
----|----|------|
0101| 1  | 100
0101| 1  | 200
0101| 2  | 300
0102| 2  | 400
0102| 2  | 500
0102| 1  | 600
0102| 1  | 700
0203| 1  | 800
0203| 2  | 900
0203| 2  | 100
```

I would like to SUM all prices in same category of same day. 
**The result of select query should look like this:**

```
date cat.  price
----|----|------|
0101| 1  | 300
0101| 2  | 300
0102| 1  | 1300
0102| 2  | 900
0203| 1  | 800
0203| 2  | 1000
```

I tired several selects which came on my mind, but not a single one which would work. I just do not know to SUM grouped by something and distinted by something else from same table in same select. Can you help me?

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempted queries.  This is a basic `group by` aggregation query.

Comment: Either you have the expected result wrong[Sum(price) for 101 and 1 should be 300 per your phrasing] or you want something else.

Comment: Thank you toddlermonet, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like...

```
select date, categories, sum(price)
from tablename
group by date, categories
```

Comment: Thank you @user3447456 I'll snap myself twice. I was using AND instead of simple comma in GROUP BY definition all the time. Outcome is than single line with SUM for all prices. It drove me mad. Thank you again.

Comment: It really is amazing how often little things slip. Happens to me every day!

Answer (score 0):

If the table above was a orders table with columns OrderDate and Amount then, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT  ORDERS.ORDER_DATE
, SUM(ORDERS.AMOUNT_BILLED)
FROM ORDERS ORDERS  
GROUP BY ORDERS.ORDER_DATE
```

Hope this gives you a starting point.

Yes, it would really help if you have your table and column names labelled. Best way would be to start writing and show some work...

Best